# Change field options after form has been filled with data

Tags: 7, entities

When creating my form, I wasn't enough aware of the configuration for the default core description field. I don't want a summary field, but I did not pay much attention at that  when setting my form in the past. Now, when I try to change the field options to remove the summary field, I get the message "There is data for this field in the database. The field settings can no longer be changed.". Is it possible to override this restriction and force the change?

Comment: I think you may want to rephrase the question. If I understand it good, you want to remove or alter the setting of a field from a content-type. But you can't because contents of this type have already been created.

Comment: Yes, you have got it right. Only the main portion of the body field (whose properties I want to change). It presents the administrator with an optional aggregated summary field, which I want to remove because I won't use it. Although the field has already been set, I have never used this summary associated with the body field. Now I have the dilemma of deleting the whole content I have created so far in order to do the body  field change or keep the configuration I don't want for this field; this is why I was wondering if someone had a solution  for "forcing" the field option change...

Comment: See: [How can I remove items from the allowed values list of a select field that has data for the values?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112315/how-can-i-remove-items-from-the-allowed-values-list-of-a-select-field-that-has-d/118980)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the type is `Long Text with Summary`. If thats the case, can't you just go to admin/structure/types/manage/`[your content type]`/fields/`[your field name]` and uncheck `Summary input`.

Drupal will then automatically create a summary if it's required to, just as it would if you had chosen `Long Text` (without summary).

Comment: Hehehe, oh, gee, yes, I can. I was looking into */field-settings but the summary has nothing to do with it, it is in the EDIT tab. Thank you for the answer...